# The query against the database caused an error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, external-list

I have two farms.

I restored a custom SQL Server database from farm1 to farm2.

After this when I try to access my external list which fetches data from one of the tables, it is showing error:

```
The query against the database caused an error
```

It is also showing following in error logs.

```
Authentication Authorization    Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UseIdentityName=0#.w|mydomain\myaccount, ClaimsCount=25
```

Looks like this is some kind of authorization error. How to solve it?

**EDIT**
By the way farm2 already had that database and it was working fine. Problem happened when I restored a new copy of database from farm1 to farm2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. In new database, I have added a new field and the external content type was not updated based on this new field hence the error.